# Python 3 Context Manager Mock Unit Test

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have the following bit of code.

```
import yaml

def load_yaml_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        data = yaml.load(f)

    return data
```

Is there a way to mock the `open` part so that f becomes `'{"hello":"world"}'` and thus I can assert that data is properly returned.

I tried to mock open with `mock_open.return_value.__enter__.return_value = '{"hello":"world"}'` and couldn't get it to work properly.

I'm using pytest and mocker.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but are you sure you need `yaml.load()` and that `yaml.safe_load()` wouldn't do the job? Even if you need to load specific objects from the standard Python library, it is better to register those explicitly for safe_loading, than to use the potentially unsafe `load()`

Comment: Anthon - Very very good point, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMERS**

- This solution does not use Mocker, but can be used with pytest.
- This solution works for Python >= 3.6

As you said you are using Mocker, I will assume that you are working on a very old codebase (<= 2.6). I highly recommend you port you code to any version >= 3.6

Since Python 3.3 mock is integrated to standard lib in [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) and is a pretty much clone from [old mock package](https://pypi.org/project/mock/)

The mock lib has a feature called [mock_open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.mock_open) that does exactly what you need and has an example with exactly what you want.

```
with patch('__main__.open', mock_open(read_data='bibble')) as m:
    with open('foo') as h:
        result = h.read()

m.assert_called_once_with('foo')
assert result == 'bibble'
```

Adapting the solution to your need you can use this example

```
import yaml
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open

def load_yaml_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        data = yaml.load(f)

    return data

with patch('__main__.open', mock_open(read_data='{"hello":"world"}')) as m:
    res = load_yaml_file('foo')

assert res == {"hello":"world"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set `__enter__` at all. Just pass in the data you want read as the `read_data` argument to `mock_open()`:

```
mocked_open = mock.mock_open(read_data='{"hello":"world"}')
with mock.patch("yourmodule.open", mocked_open):
    result = load_yaml_file("foobar.yaml")
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> def load_yaml_file(filename):
...     with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
...         data = yaml.load(f)
...     return data
...
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> mocked_open = mock.mock_open(read_data='{"hello":"world"}')
>>> with mock.patch("__main__.open", mocked_open):
...     result = load_yaml_file("foobar.yaml")
...
>>> print(result)
{'hello': 'world'}
>>> mocked_open.mock_calls
[call('foobar.yaml', 'rt'),
 call().__enter__(),
 call().read(4096),
 call().read(4096),
 call().__exit__(None, None, None)]
```